# How should I rebuild MuPDF from official focal source avoiding "lcms2mt.h: No such file or directory" message?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dependencies, compiling

I was trying to update my own [answer here at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1208373/66509) because of a comment below it.

What I have done:

1. Created fresh 20.04.3 LTS VM with all updates
2. Enabled all deb-src repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by

   ```
   sudo sed -i "s/# deb-src/deb-src/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Installed all needed build-dependencies by

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep mupdf
   ```
4. Downloaded source code of MuPDF by

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   apt-get source mupdf
   ```
5. Tried to compile the sources by

   ```
   cd mupdf-1.16.1+ds1/
   make
   ```

   and here I get the following error message

   > ```
   >      ...
   >      CC build/release/source/fitz/color-lcms.o
   >  source/fitz/color-lcms.c:36:10: fatal error: lcms2mt.h: No such file or directory
   >  36 | #include "lcms2mt.h"
   >  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
   >  compilation terminated.
   >  make: *** [Makefile:126: build/release/source/fitz/color-lcms.o] Error 1
   > ```

And what is interesting:

1. the mentioned `lcms2mt.h` is [not contained in any deb-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=lcms2mt.h).
2. on the same system `apt-get source -b mupdf` succeeds.

Comment: v1.19.0 ? Ubuntu 20.04 has v1.16.0 ?. No issues with either → The deb build files seem *not* to use the missing thirdparty headers → `$ apt-get -b source mupdf`: The 5 packages.deb are built. (I used Ubuntu 21.10 for v1.19.0). ..... Other method: `git clone https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf.git && cd mupdf/ && git submodule update --init --recursive`: Provides thirdparty///{~1492 headers}. ..... `$ make`: No issues.

Comment: Oh, thanks, very useful. It was a typo - really the folder is named *mupdf-1.16.1+ds1* on 20.04 LTS. @KnudLarsen Could you please repeat all my above steps on 20.04 LTS as they are written without involving github?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.3: I did "step 1 - 4" OK, step 5 fails, missing lcms2mt.h, lcms2mt_plugin.h, jbig2.h and probably more. .... Hence "apt-get **-b** source mupdf", i.e. option **-b** will build mupdf using the ~30? build files in `mupdf-1.16.1+ds1/debian/`